# WiX differences on 64-bit?

Tags: wix, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

What are all the things we should take care of while writing a WiX installer for 64-bit software?

What if I want to support both 32- and 64-bit versions?

I want to release **one version** of the installer, that will be possible to install softwares for both platforms, according to the host OS.

Answer (score 1):

Separate MSIs for separate architectures:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

and people use a WiX bundle to choose which depending on the system.

You can have a common source file for both MSIs, this kind of thing:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/08/09/4317654.aspx

http://alekdavis.blogspot.com/2011/05/build-32-and-64-bit-installers-using.html